# how can i convert stl to my vb6 programs file type

Tags: vb6

how can i convert stl to the file type of my vb6 program.
My vb6 program is a 3d viewer, the file type is .prt.
.prt is a mesh model, just like stl (not unigraphics .prt).
This file type is special, only my vb6 program can read it.
This is the file type of my vb6 project (.prt)

Inside the file:

[image]

please help me.

Comment: First thing would be to understand the format and definition of the stl file format. I don't know how much documentation is available for that, but there is at least a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) to start on. Once you understand that, you need to know the convert-to format, since this is proprietary to your program, only you'll know what that is, therefore this conversion is a task that it would seem that only you can perform.

Comment: You will need to write code to read the stl file.  This is likely not a trivial task so I would look into a library to help with the endeavor.  Once you can read the file then you can convert the information to your prt format.

Comment: i know, i have ascii stl. tons of vertex

Comment: Instead of converting an stl file to the proprietary format, you could consider adding support for the stl file format to your program. Then you'd be able to directly use any stl file out there?

Comment: I have to say it isn't really clear what the *specific* problem you are having is... is it a VB6 issue? Something about STL? Something else?  You should edit your question to try and narrow it down. Feel free to ask multiple independent (but focused) questions as well.

Comment: stayontarget isa not issue Markl i dont know i get a source code

Comment: You should look around and look for a program that already handles STL files on some level, esp ASCII ones?  Then, you're not writing your own library, at least not from scratch.  Or find programs that have a portion of the functionality you want to provide (i.e., reading the STL file from VB6/VBA).  For example, a short search turns up this program:  http://5axes.free.fr/devel_stl_en.htm  It might not be perfect, but you may be able to extract something from here to save you some time on the reading in side.  For the output, you know your format best..  You likely have to write it yourself.

Comment: pick stl not works with my stl